# Why would the tribes choose to stay?

Tags: internal-consistency

A nuclear apocalypse happens and what not. 500 years later the region of Southern California has devolved into primitive and backwards tribes that are often at war with each other.

In this story, my main character helps one tribe defeat two others in a war to control the water resources in the area.

The thing is, it would make more sense for the clans to just relocate somewhere else instead of staying. My question is, what would be a logical reason for the tribes to not leave the area?

Comment: Welcome to the site, Talos. This questions seems to be about plot elements of a story, not about designing aspects of a world. For plot based questions, there are as many different answers as there are people with imagination. Here at Worldbuilding, we want to have questions that have only a single 'right' answer. I'm voting to close this as 'primarily story based.' You could rephrase your question as a reality check, where you propose a solution as ask us if it works: "Is X a logical reason for tribe to not leave the area?"

Comment: Glad to see another Fallout fan. I think the question is primarily opinion based, though - why people choose to stay or go is usually personal and emotional.

Comment: If you ignore the origin, this is simply a situation that has arisen countless times in history with every variation and outcome imaginable.  History will tell you that sense has little to do with why things happen.

Comment: The radiation is gone after 10 years.  The bullets are gone or useless after 100 years.  After 200 years all the plant life has grown back.  Moving a community is a pain, it's usually easier to fight than to migrate unless the opponent has overwhelming force.  But my real question is, since most of the world's tech was developed in the last 150 of our years, why are they still primitive?  They should have been back to sending satellites into orbit 200 years ago.

Comment: @StephenG : "History will tell you that sense has little to do with why things happen" you should perhaps look more to Geography then (the bit of the curriculum my teacher called human geography when I was at school), it nearly always makes sense, you might ask why people continue to build & live on flood planes, the answer is as my teacher continually repeated "cheap flat land", not to mention ready availability of water for drinking, transport & industry (in earlier times), if (in hindsight) you don't know why (the broader flow of) history is as it is you're just not looking at it right.

Comment: @Renan : Why "individuals" choose to stay or go often is personal & emotional yes, but why "populations" stay or go is not (especially over extended time-frames of many generations), population movement on the broader historic scale can both be modeled & predicted.

Comment: @JBH : You need not just the knowledge but adequate social structures to back both development & implementation of stuff like satellites, if society is still fractious & tribal it wouldn't happen, an individual modern city can't float it's own space program (for obvious reasons) so a largely agrarian tribal society certainly couldn't, society would need to aggregate back into something like a nation first, politics being politics once broken into small tribal factions that could conceivably take a very long time.

Comment: For the same reason that other tribes (Inuit and Berbers) still live in barren, seemingly uninhabitable places.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding! We've noticed that you changed the contents of the question - when a question is closed, it's not at all required or important to physically remove the main body of the question, especially once answered. The question you had isn't a *bad question* or anything - unfortunately, it just won't be able to get good answers from us, here, as we're best at answering questions about *building* worlds, as opposed to figuring out what the best thing to do in a story is, or in this case, reasons for the plot doing what it does in the specific way that you're looking for

Comment: In this case, as you're using the reality-check tag, something that's more likely to get good answers here would be to come up with a possible reasoning, related to the world that you've created and ask if that is a realistic world. As an example heading towards the right direction, you could ask about the plausibility of a world where other watering spots move around quite a lot or change in size, which puts it into the context of *building a world*, as opposed to looking for thoughts about a specific plot, which is something that's ultimately up to you and something that we can't answer

Comment: @Talos : You clearly discovered the edit tab, because you've edited this, but if you're replacing this question with the duplicate you started (rather than editing this one) can you please delete this one properly .. use the tab called delete next to the one called edit that you found & used to edit this.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Please don't quasi-delete questions with edits like that; it takes away the context from existing answers.  Thanks.  I know the rules can be a little confusing; our community is trying to help you, even if it's a little frustrating for you.  I'm sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Because they can't leave without putting themselves in danger.

- There are other tribes living around. In order to take their area,
  the tribe would have to fight them.
- Large parts of the region is a desert and a nuclear war is not going to
  make the area more livable. They are surrounded by deserts and/or
  mountains and the most likely place to settle is far away. The trip
  to get there could be dangerous.

Comment: Add in the tropes of mutated animals etc...